# using a <a> to run a function()

Tags: jquery, function, hyperlink, tags

I was wondering will this  link call the function I want?

```
<a href="http://catalog.bitsltd.us/power_strips#replaced" onclick="document.getElementById('caShip').function caShip()" id="caShip">Some Text</a>
```

and this is the function I want to call... Can anyone tell me why it is not working also?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function caShip(){
    $('#caShip').replaceWith('Some HTML (the new HTML has an id of replaced)');
});
</script>
```

When the link is clicked it does go to the href, which is the same page and an ID, but it doesn't replace the < a > with the new HTML, which is a < div >?

UPDATE: THIS IS THE WORKING CODE:

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Hide Canadian Information
    $('.locationDiv').hide();

    //bind the links click events
    $('.locLink').click(function(){       
        $('#1').hide();
        $('#desc_' + $(this).attr('title')).show();
    });
});     

</script>
```

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="can" class="locLink" id="1">Canadian Customers Click Here Before Ordering!</a>
<div id="desc_can" class="locationDiv">
    <table class="contentpaneopen">
      <tr>
        <td class="contentheading" width="100%">Attention Canadian Customers!
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="contentpaneopen">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" >
        <span class="body">Please note that there are fees associated with shipping to Canada from the US that are <b><u><i><font color="red">NOT</font></i></u></b> included in the cost of the shipping or the cost of the unit. These cost are to be paid for by the purchaser. Here are some tips for shipping to Canada:
        <br />
        <br />
        -USPS methods are cheap but very unreliable. <b>Border fees</b> are not charged using USPS, only UPS or Fed Ex (which are the most reliable).
        <br />
        -<b>Customs fees</b> can sometime run <b>up to 50%</b> of the purchase price (UPS/FedEx).
        <br />
        -Smart Strips are available from a Canadian dealer. Visit our <a href="index.php?Itemid=146" title="Store Locator" target="_blank">Store Locator</a> to find a local seller.
        <br />
        -Customers with a UPS or FedEx account may ship on their account and assume all fees with no delays.
        <br />
        -Canadian customers selecting UPS or FedEx will have to pick the package up at their local station and pay the fees. So you order it online, but still have to drive and pay to pick it up unless you used your own UPS/Fed Ex account.</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I didn't use the CSS because I can achieve what I need without it. Thanks to everyone that was trying to help me with this!!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

**HTML**

```
<a href="#replaced" id="caShip">Some Text</a>
```

**JS**

```
$('#caShip').click(function(){
    $(this).text('Some HTML (the new HTML has an id of replaced)');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8bUKs/1/

Comment: I was a little late on this one. ha.

Comment: I would do this exactly except that I can't just use '#replaced' as the href because the page has a base URL that is different than the current page. I have done this trying everyone's suggestions with no luck. It reloads the page but doesn't replace the <a> with the HTML in the js.

Comment: That's because when it reloads the page, anything you do with JS will be reset, since it's client side.

Comment: So how would I call the function on the reload? Can I?

Comment: If your link is bringing you to a different page, it would be up that page to detect where you've come from and display the correct text accordingly. Javascript is only used (when it comes to changing elements on the screen) for the page you are currently on. Once you leave that page, you leave all changes as well. Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do makes it tough.

Comment: the link is not bringing me to a different page. The link will reload the current page. I was saying that the base URL is http://'www.someURL.com/' and the pages actual URL is http://'www.a completely different URL.com/' (ignore the single quotes). This is done this way for other site needs. I am simply trying to replace some content on the page with other content. It will start with some text. What element the text is inside is not too important to me. I want the jquery to change the starting element with the new one when someone clicks the starting element.

Comment: My point is you can't have jQuery do something if your going to refresh the page, or navigate to the new one. The point of having JS change an element is to avoid another page load. Javascript can only effect the page the script resides on (for the sake of this discussion). What is the point of refreshing the page when the link is clicked? Im trying to understand so I can help you. Can you give me specifics?

Comment: OK well I tried to do this on just text, in a div, but it didn't do anything. Thats why I made it a link (I figured maybe it needed to be something that can be "clicked") how would you recommend to do this?

Comment: I need you to explain to me, in detail, exactly what you are trying to accomplish..from start to finish

Comment: OK here goes. We are a US based company. We have Canadian customers that need some information before ordering. The page has a lot of information already on it. I was trying to have just some regular text that says "Canadian Customers Click here before ordering." Then when they clicked the text the jquery would replace the text with the information that the Canadian customers need. The reason for doing it this way is because not everyone will need to view this information so I wanted it to be viewable dynamically by user input (clicking the text). Anything you don't understand?

Comment: Yes. If you are going to refresh the page, you need to pass a variable into the URL when you refresh the page like `http://catalog.bitsltd.us/power_strips?location=canada` - if you are not going to refresh the page, then you'll use JavaScript. The bottom line is you need to let the 2nd refreshed page know what to display, and then use the server-side code handle the different information sets..

Comment: I don't WANT to refresh the page that is just what was happening when it was a link I was trying to use. I would prefer using a div and not refreshing the page. E.G.: it will start out as a div with text and when clicked it would remove the old div and anything within and replace it with the new div. Can you help me with that, please? And thanks for all of the help and time so far!

Comment: If you don't want to refresh the page, then you're saying when the link is clicked, the visitor stays on the same page, and additional information is displayed in a div?

Comment: Kinda but still not quite. It does not have to be a link (Unless it HAS to be something clickable to work). I would prefer it not to be a link. I just want a div with some html that says a short message. Then when that message, preferably not a link; again unless it has to be a click-able item to work, is clicked the one div with the short message is removed and the div with the new html is added without refreshing the page. I will try the above... looks promising even though it uses links.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it to work... I only needed the one link to display the one div with info. I have updated my original question with the WORKING code. Again THANKS for your help... how do I mark this question solved?

Comment: Thanks for the support and getting back to me on the end result. Glad I could be helpful...

Answer (score 4):

No.

Get rid of the inline `onclick` attribute, and just do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#caShip').click(function() {
        $(this).replaceWith('<div id="' + this.hash.slice(1) + '">some HTML</div>');
           // uncomment the next line if you want the hash to actually appear.
        // window.location.hash = this.hash;

           // prevent the page from reloading
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

If you did want it inline, you could just do this:

```
<a href="http://catalog.bitsltd.us/power_strips#replaced" onclick="caShip.call(this);" id="caShip">Some Text</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
function caShip(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<div id="' + this.hash.slice(1) + '">some HTML</div>');
}
</script>
```

---

**EDIT:** *Fixed it to use the `hash` from the Anchor element to create a new element with that ID, since that's what the text used for the replacement seems to imply.*

Comment: In this situation this is definately the way to go. However, its not always you (want to) know the id of the element who calls a function. Or it could be by design. Both ways work just fine and in this example i think the jquery click() is awesome!

Comment: doesn't seem to work. reloads the page but no change. The old HTML is still in the page.

Comment: @MJ3111: If it's the same page that you're currently on (sounds like it is), then you can change the `href` of the `<a>` to `"#replaced"` instead of the full domain and pathname. If that's not an option, then we'll need to prevent the default behavior of the `<a>`, and manually update the hash to `#replaced`. Let me know.

Comment: ...if you can't change the `href`, and we do need to prevent the default behavior of the `<a>`, you'll need to let me know if you're still using the inline `onclick` or not. The solution will be a little different.

Comment: If at all possible I would like to not use a link.... the href has to be the full URL because the page has a base URL that is different than the page's actual URL. This is done this way intentionally. I do not want to use the inline onclick. I would prefer it to be just some text in a div at first that is replaced with some different text within a div. When I tried that it wouldn't work for me either.

Comment: @MJ3111: If by *"I would like to not use a link"* you're saying that you would prefer to not use the inline `onclick`, then remove that, and use my first example, but add `return false;` inside the handler. I'll update. I'll also add a line that manually adds the `hash` to the `window.location` if you wanted that to appear.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but if you look at my original question I have updated it with the working code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="http://catalog.bitsltd.us/power_strips#replaced" onclick="caShipFunc();" id="caShip">Some Text</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function caShipFunc(){
      $('#caShip').replaceWith('Some HTML (the new HTML has an id of replaced)');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, you should do something like this:

```
<a href="http://catalog.bitsltd.us/power_strips#replaced" id="caShip">Some Text</a>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){       
    $('#caShip').click(function() {
        if($(this).attr('href').indexOf("#") != -1) {
            $('#caShip').replaceWith('<div>Test</div>');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**EDIT:** Updated the jQuery to address your comment. This works in my very basic testing.

Comment: No Luck. Page reloads but no change.

Comment: @MJ3111 I've updated my answer with some new jQuery that worked for me in some small tests I did on my end.

Comment: 2 questions... One: were the double quotes intentional? .indexOf("#"). And 2 does the first closing bracket need a ";"? I think I need to figure out how to do this without reloading the page. Any Suggestions? I did try the update with no luck

Comment: Thanks for the help. If you look at my original question you will see my working code.

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing jQuery and not actually declaring a function.

Writing `$(function someName() { ... })` creates a named function expression and passes it to the `$` function.
It doesn't declare a reusable function; you cannot then write `someName()`.

In addition, your call in the `onclick` handler is completely wrong.
In order to call a function, you should just call it (`onclick="caShip();"`); you can't combine it with `getElementById`.

The correct way to do this is to add a `click` handler using jQuery:

```
$(function() { 
    $('#caShip').click(function() {
        $(this).replaceWith('Some HTML (the new HTML has an id of replaced)');
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried this and I would guess the HTML part of your suggestion would be similar to Michael I or Dutchie? If that is correct then it didn't help. The HTML isn't being replaced. It seems that the page is reloading (because of the href I would assume). Maybe doing it this way I would need to call the function when the page reloads? Is that possible? Also I can't just use '#reloaded' as the href because the page has a different base URL.

Comment: Thanks for the help. If you look at my original question I have updated it with the working code.